# What would be the standard naming approach for python loggers inside python libraries?

Tags: python, logging

There are several ways to name a logger inside a python library and until recently I had the impression that I was using the correct one.

1. `logger = logging.getLogger("foobar")`
2. `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`
3. `logger = logging.getLogger(__package__)`

I don't like the first because it may require change if the library names is renamed.

My fav one was `__name__` but someone pointed that this may be a meaningless name if your code is inside a different file inside a module, also it would change if you start reorganizing the code inside your python library. For example if you have modules named like `session`, `client` or so their name does not make much sense.

They pointed that `__package__` should be a better name and I kinda agree with this. Still, doing a bit of google search regarding popularity it was surprised to find that less than `1%` of people are using `__package__` when compared to popularity of `__name__`.

I know that the logging module supports dot names but I really don't see anyone doing a `logger = logging.getLogger(__package__ + '.' + __name__)` which seems to be really ugly.

Another less important question would be regarding `logger` vs `log` for the name of the variable keeping the logger instance.

Comment: Name it whatever helps you diagnose those logs later on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is about libraries that are published and used by others, is not about what helps "me".